# Android camera preview orientation issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, camera, orientation

I am working on an app that takes an image and and previews it in the same activity by hiding the capture button and showing the imageview with drawn bitmap from the camera. Is there a way to lock the current orrientation while a user views the image  and changes the orientation of the device?

Edited

Because during the preview mode if the orientation was changed, I used `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden`

and I handled the bitmap in another Activity

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest try this.

```
<activity
        android:name=“.activityYouWantToLock"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it programmatically like this:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```